# Is it a good idea to implement chatroom like functionality via pubsubhub

Tags: java, websub

Actually I want something between chatroom and stackoverflow ie users can ask questions and in my application generally many users will be on the same webpage now others can see the question in realtime and answer the same in realtime ie kind of chatroom type app.

I want to implement it via pubsubhub any suggestions ideas if this is a good idea or not.

Any java system having this functionality will be helpful.

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 2):

I think You can use IRC (Internet Chat Relay ) here for that..

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a perfect match for [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). [Pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) is better suited for near-realtime server-to-server kinda things.

Comment: Thanks for the info but as far as I am aware that Gogle Buzz is also based on Pubsubhubbub and I need something similar.

Comment: @saurabh I doubt that Buzz is using it to display data on the UI. I think it's only using pubsubhubbub for content aggregation and publishing, hence server-to-server kinda things